# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Default Drivers Removed?

Tags: wireless, drivers

During a recent software update on my HP Elitebook 8530w running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the Software Update crashed after partially downloading a selection of updates. Since then it appears that some of my machines default drivers (monitor, wifi, etc) have either been corrupted or removed.

I cannot find a way of reinstating or reinstalling the base set of drivers for my hardware. The wifi card is: Intel WiFi Link 5300

I cannot boot from DVD to reinstall Ubuntu from DVD.

Any advice greatly appreciated. Pleas let me know if there's any additional system info that I can post to give more detail.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you get into recovery mode? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Answer (score 0):

The driver for your device is *iwlwifi*. This driver and it's associated components are included in their entirety in each successive kernel version; for example:

```
/lib/modules/3.19.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
/lib/modules/3.19.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
/lib/modules/4.0.1-040001-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
```

You can test by rebooting, getting the GRUB menu and selecting an earlier kernel version than the very latest: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

You can also try reinstalling the current kernel version, known in Ubuntu as linux-image:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-`uname -r`
```

Those backticks are on the left side of my keyboard on the same key with ~.

Some Intel wireless devices can be tricky to get working smoothly. If this doesn't resolve your issue, I will edit my answer to propose other steps.